# Milestone Page layout

Tags: casemilestone

Where we can use this page layout
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Service cloud in Salesforce has one feature called [**Entitlement**](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=entitlements_about.htm) which helps you provide the correct support to your customers. It includes a variety of features that let you define, enforce, and track service levels as part of your case management process. milestone is one of them.

[image]

So Once we assign Entitlement for a customer and we create a case for that customer system generate milestones for that customer on the basis of entitlement. We can add Case Milestone related list on Case layout and from there you can go for milestone detail page as shown below.

[image]

Reference video: [Entitlement setup in Salesforce](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NoWAJ_vZgE)

Comment: Could you tell me, How can i see the records in case milestones related list?

Comment: Watch answered video it will give you better understanding so create entitlement process first. assign contract to account and while create case select entitlement.